# How to use regex to replace foo(.*) with (foo <what was inside the parenthesis before>)?

Tags: regex, variables, vim, alias, replaceall

Are there mechanisms to replace all, using regex, but keeping what was matched by `".*"` ?

If this is not part of regex, but is possible in some editors, please state accordingly.

Comment: Converting to lisp, by chance?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want you separate "foo" from what is in the parentheses by a space, and then surround the whole thing with parentheses:

`:%s/foo\(.*\)/(foo \1)/g`

In that the `\1` represents the text in the first parentheses.  You could use `\2` if you had another parentheses grouping, etc.

Given you had
`fooMOO`

you'd end up with:
`(foo MOO)`

Comment: What does :%s/ stand for? Anything to do with vim?

Comment: the : starts command mode, the % says "do the whole file", and s starts a substitution command.  100% vim-related.

Answer (score 1):

You can use backreferences in the substitution pattern:

```
%s/foo(\(.*\))/foo \1/g
```

In this pattern, the unescaped parentheses match the actual parentheses in the text whereas the escaped parentheses act as capturing parentheses.  The \1 is the backreference, which refers to everything that was matched inside the first set of capturing parentheses in the regular expression.  Note that if you might have multiple function calls on a single line, you'll probably want to limit how many characters you match.  If there's no danger of having a close parenthesis within the argument list to foo() (for example, in a string) then you'll probably want to do that by not matching close parentheses:

```
%s/foo(\([^)]\))/foo \1/g
```

If there is a danger of having a close parenthesis inside the argument list then things get complicated.